# Connect java to Apache Spark Sql

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I have configured Hadoop 3.2.1 successfully on Ubuntu OS single node.
I have configured Spark version 3.0.0-preview2 too. Default metastore is Derby.

I created a database (dbname = d1) and table (name = dm1) in HDFS using Spark successfully.

Now, i'm trying to query it from Java with Spark SQL but getting the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: d1.dm1; line 1 pos 14; 
'Project [*] 
 +- 'UnresolvedRelation [d1, dm1]
```

my code is bellow:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.Builder().master("local[*]").appName("testing").getOrCreate();    
Dataset<Row> data = spark.sql("select * from d1.dm1");
```

Could someone please tell me what the issue is?

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
   <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.3</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-preview2</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
   <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: _"Default metadata is Derby"_ > you mean a volatile, in-memory, embedded database that is not persisted from one Spark execution to another? That would explain your problem.